# I'm trying to install rasa and came up with this error, can anyone please help me

Tags: pip, rasa

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sajay\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sajay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u_bz_626\\rasa-core_84280aa7583e425f97008a96c12af162\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sajay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u_bz_626\\rasa-core_84280aa7583e425f97008a96c12af162\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\sajay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-zfh3b0z2'
         cwd: C:\Users\sajay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u_bz_626\rasa-core_84280aa7583e425f97008a96c12af162\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\sajay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u_bz_626\rasa-core_84280aa7583e425f97008a96c12af162\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        import pypandoc
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypandoc'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\sajay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u_bz_626\rasa-core_84280aa7583e425f97008a96c12af162\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        readme = open('README.md').read()
      File "c:\users\sajay\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 882: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Hi, I believe your query is more suitable for the Rasa community forum: https://forum.rasa.com or Github: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa, where it appears that there is a related issue for it: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/1872

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the Operating system and version of rasa and python you are using for Installation?

Prebuilt wheels for Windows and Mac OS X include pandoc.
If you use Linux and have your own wheelhouse, you can build a wheel which include pandoc with python setup.py download_pandoc; python setup.py bdist_wheel. Be aware that this works only on 64bit intel systems

Use correct version of Python

[image]

The error you are receiving normally comes when there is version compatibility issue!

Comment: My Operating system is Windows 10 and python is 3.9.0...

Comment: Yeah Try with 3.6 or 3.7 python version.